# Valid CoreOS multi tenancy scenario?

Tags: docker, coreos

I'm currently tinkering with a scenario for using CoreOS. It's probably not the 1st class use case. But I'd like to get a pointer if it's valid though. As I'm really at the beginning of getting a grip on CoreOS I hope that my "use case" is not totally off.

Imagine a multi tenant application where every tenant should get it's own runtime environment. Let's take a web app running on Node.js and PostgreSQL for data storage as given. Each tenant environment would be be running on CoreOS in their respective containers. Data persistance is left out for now. For me it's currently more about the general feasibility.

So why CoreOS?

Currently I try to stick with the idea of separated environments per tenant. To optimise the density of DB and web server instances per hardware host I thought CoreOS might be the right choice instead of "classic" virtualisation.

Another reason is that a lot of tenants might not need more than a single, smallish DB instance and a single, smallish web server. But there might be other tenants that need some constantly scaled out deployments. Others might need a temporary scale out during burst times. CoreOS sounds like a good fit here as well.

On the other side there must be a scalable messaging infrastructure (RabbitMQ) in behind that will handle a lot of messages. This infrastructure will be used by all tenants and needs to dynamically scalable at best. Probably there will be a "to be scaled" Elasticsearch infrastructure as well. Viewed through my current "CoreOS for everything goggles" this seems a good fit as well.

In case this whole scenario is generally valid, I currently cannot see how it would be possible to route the traffic for a general available web site to the different tenant containers.

Imagine the app is running at app.greatthing.tld. A user can login and should be presented the app served for it's tenant. Is this something socketplane and/or flannel are there to solve? Or how would a solution look like to get the tenant served by the right containers? I think it's kind of a general issue. But at least in the context of a CoreOS containerized environment I cannot see how to deal with this at all.

Answer (score 1):

CoreOS takes care of scheduling your container in the cluster with their own tools such as fleetctl/etcd/systemd and also takes care of persistent storage when resheduled to a different container using flocker (experimental). They have their own load balancers.